# xml запрос средствами XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Нужно отправить xml методом на ресурс запрос

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request version="1.0">
  <merchant>
    <id>75482</id>
    <signature>fsdfdsSfSDfsdfsd#2g23423</signature>
  </merchant>
</request>
```

Я пытаюсь отправть так

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xmlQuery = ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
                    <request version="1.0">\
                       <merchant>\
                         <id>75482</id>\
                         <signature>fsdfdsSfSDfsdfsd#2g23423</signature>\
                          </merchant>\
                        </request>';

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4){
            var res = req.responseXML;
            console.log(req.responseXML);

        }
    }

    req.open("POST", "http://site.ru/xml", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
    req.send(xmlQuery);
```

В ответ мне должен прийти тоже ХМЛ, но мне приходит
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Почитал про это  - сказано что в мерах безопасности нельзя отсылать на другой домен, что можно как то через прокси (не подходит увы), через php сервер (тоже не подходит) и еще какие - то способы..

**Так вот вопрос, вообще правильно ли я пытаюсь отослать хмл методом хмл запрос или нет?**

Как я понял проблема вторая когда приходит ошибка - это мера безопасности...

Answer (score 2):

Решил вопрос вот так:

Через XHR дал запрос на сервер ( на свой сервер ) а сервер уже через CURL обратился к ихнему серверу, и все работает.

```
$xml = ["xml" => "Код запроса XML"]

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "На какой ЮРЛ запрос идет");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_exec($curl);
```

И дальше уже всякие условия что приходит,  и так далее